# Saving Files (Images) to MongoDB with MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongodb

I am building an angular application with a MongoDB based Database. I am trying to create a feature that will allow users to upload files and save them in the DB. I have built out the drag and drop UI and believe that Angular is sending the `.png`correctly, however, the object saved in the MongoDB doesn't include any content (as confirmed by the debug and by GUI inspection of DB).

Any ideas why my API is losing the content of the file it's saving?

[image]

`fileDrop.component.ts` :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-select',
  templateUrl: './data-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-select.component.scss']
})
export class DataSelectComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataSelectService: DataSelectService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  public files: NgxFileDropEntry[] = [];

  public dropped(files: NgxFileDropEntry[]) {
    this.files = files;
    for (const droppedFile of files) {

        const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
        fileEntry.file((file: File) => {

          const formData: any = new FormData()
          formData.append('img', file, droppedFile.relativePath)

          // Debug HERE - file is correctly populated 

          this.dataSelectService.register(file).subscribe(res => {
            // Debug HERE - file just returns an Object ID
          });
        });
    }
  }

}
```

`dataSelect.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataSelectService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  register(data: File): Observable<File> {
    return this.http.post<File>('/api/image', data);
  }
}
```

The on the backend -

`image.model.ts`:

```
const imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  desc: String,
  user: String,
  img:
  {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String
  }
});

const Image = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);

export default Image;
```

then the controller function saving to the DB:

```
  insert = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const obj = await new this.model(req.body).save();
      res.status(201).json(obj);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
    }
  }
```

I am suspicious about the formatting of the data. In most examples I can see online, people tend to use intermediate local file storage (usually with Multer), so the API receives the image and then saves it to the local system before uploading it to the DB.

I don't see why you would want to add the additional complexity?

Other discussions tend to focus on the GRIDFS data type for saving files. However, I believe this is only for files > 16MB. I am using images < 1MB, so I don't think this is relevant. But is there a special data type I should be using or some kind of encoding?

However, even if I intercept the data before it is written to the DB, with -

```
imageSchema.pre('save', function (next): void {
  const image = this;
  console.log(image);
  next();
});
```

I get an output like

> { _id: 60b90a95e3c52664e982b480 }

with no record attached?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send `name`, `desc`, `user` when updating a file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I believe that all fields in a mongoose schema are optional by default (except _id). So I am not sure this is it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if you don't send relation fields value, how did you check image uploaded for user?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the question? I have not implemented the login logic in my app yet, so there is no user id set.

Comment: Ah, I got it. then can you try to use encode base64?
In frontend, you can send file content to base64 then, the server will save.
If it is not saving to database, your backend has some issue, I think. Thank you